# Hide the data of a user which has the same "Role"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

For the role `Former`, I have 2 users. For example `Eric` wants to see his private informations. He can see the private informations of `Jean`. It's a problem...

[image]

Can I block that

I have tried this but without success:

```
$has_role = auth()->user()->hasRole('former'); 

$user = User::when($has_role, function ($query) {
    return $query->where('email', auth()->user()->email);
})
->get();
```

My file index.blade.php

```
@foreach($formers as $former)
    <tr>
      <td> {{$former->name}}</td>
      <td> {{$former->firstname}}</td>
      etc...
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$has_role` is true?

Comment: Why you send all collection of users while you can get it by user id Auth think about that you have 1000 user with same role, when they click on private data your sql will take all 1000 user for each user to much query just put Auth->user("user_id") to sql query

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the current user his information only, and not allow him to see another user's information, you can do this in the blade file without having to go back to the database or send through a collection in the first place if the page is going through your `Auth` middleware.  By not sending a collection of users from your controller, you will not be able to show any other user's information to your current user (thus blocking him from seeing anything other than his own data).

On your blade page, only display the single user's information, and then perhaps only if he has the role that allows him to see that information (I'm guessing that role is called `former` for this demo).  You already have the user object on the blade page, thanks to the middleware, and it will have access to the `hasRole()` method:

```
@if (\Auth::user()->hasRole('former'))
   <td>
       \Auth::user()->name;
   </td>
   <td>
       \Auth::user()->address; // etc
   </td>
@endif
```

If you want to display other users (which I think you don't and this was the problem), you will need to pull in a collection of users from the controller and then do the same if-check to see if the current user has permission to see the other user's information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I must to use the file index.blade.php?? So, I adapt your code on my loop ?? `@foreach($formers as $former)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$former->name}}</td>
                   <td> {{$former->firstname}}</td>
                  `

Comment: No, didn't think you wanted the current user to see anything but his own information.  So, to block all the other user information, I figured you could just use the single authenticated user and just display his information.  I suggested you didn't need to make `$formers` at all, since that is information you wanted to block.  You could use this on an index.php page, but it would only show one record - so I thought it would maybe go to a 'show' page or similar.  So I thought take out the `foreach` loop totally to solve this and just use the Auth::user()

Comment: Ah Ok, I only have a page index.blade.php. I don't have of page show.php. You think it's possible to make this with a index.blade.php?

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you like with the pages... but if you ever wanted a page so that an ADMIN could see ALL users, you might want to leave the index page as it is with all formers - and the admin can see everything.  For the single view of just the current user, it might be easier to make a new show page.  Was this what you wanted, or were you trying to have all users with the role displayed and then a second if check that allowed only the user with the right permissions to see those users?

Comment: If you were asking how to get all users with the role of `former` (sorry if I misunderstood), go from the reverse for your query, like this:  `$role = Role::with('users')->where('name', 'former')->first();`  Then in your blade page, `foreach($role->users as $user)` will give you just the users with the role `former`.  You would still have the same problem as above though where Eric can see Jean - but then you can apply an if-check for Eric to see if he has the right permission to see all the other users information.  like `if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('permXX'))` in blade

Comment: In fact, the admin must see all the information of the formers. For example, we have 2 trainers (Eric and David), the admin must be able to see the information of the two trainers.

@Watercayman: On the other hand, when Eric connects, he can only see his information. So David's information is hidden. I don't know if you have understand? Sorry again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198012/discussion-between-watercayman-and-user11124425).

Answer (score 0):

**Store role in session when user log in**

and use like this in your Blade

```
@if(Session::get('role') == 'admin')
 <h1> you are admin </h1>
@else
 <h1> you are not admin </h1>
@endif
```